# Função Média não funciona

Tags: microsoft-excel

Olá, Criei varios numeros randomicos com `ALEATÓRIOENTRE()` e os concatenei com o `CONCAT()` copiei esses valores e colei em outra parte da planilha. Eu estava tentando fazer a media com `MÉDIA()` Porem ele me retorna a nenhum valor, só quando eu seleciono os valores e dou enter que ele começa a ler aquele valor. Como corrigir isso? Obrigado.[image: Planilha]

Segue tambem o link para visualizar a planilha no excel online: https://1drv.ms/x/s!At0-rSrOjtEyiWEx_Bcw2I3ogE8o

Comment: Olá, bem vindo ao SOPT. A sua pergunta não está muito clara. Sugiro colocar ao menos uma imagem da tela e também a fórmula completa da chamada da função `média`, caso contrário dificilmente alguém conseguirá te ajudar. Essa função sabidamente funciona, e provavelmente você está comentendo algum erro. Se não fez ainda, faça o [tour] e leia [ask].

Comment: Adicionei o print e um link pro excel online :)

Comment: Ok, agora sim. Retirei o voto pra fechar e respondi à pergunta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O seu problema é que você está manipulando horas como strings de texto (já que está usando a função `concat` para "juntar" hora e minutos). Como não faz sentido calcular a média de texto (a função `média` espera necessariamente valores numéricos), ela gera erro.

O que você deveria ter feito é usado o formato numérico da hora. O Excel trata horas como valores decimais de 24 horas (isto é, `00:00:00` é `0,0`, `12:00:00` é  `0,5`, `24:00:00` é `1,0`, `48:00:00` é `2,0` e assim sucessivamente). Por isso, você pode fazer a "junção" sem usar a função `concat` com a seguinte fórmula (exemplificada para o cálculo da primeira coluna):

```
=(G8+(G9/60))/24
```

Essa fórmula soma numericamente o valor da hora (coluna G8) com os minutos em decimal (isto é, coluna G9 dividida por 60, para dar a fração de hora), e aí divide tudo por 24 para calcular o valor da hora decimal esperado pelo Excel.

Note que o valor da célula onde essa fórmula vai ser colocada vai conter um número (e não uma string de texto!). Por exemlo, na imagem abaixo, a célula G18, que exibe `01:46`, na verdade contém `0,07`. Por isso, o valor dessa célula pode ser utilizado para computar uma média normalmente.

> Aliás, se você usar a máscara `[hh]:mm` na formatação da célula, você
>   pode exibir horas acima de `24` (como `28:42`), algo que talvez seja útil na exibição de carga horária acumulada, por exemplo.

O resultado é que a média funciona, como exibido abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]